# Pass Multiple arguments onMouseover event handler in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, onmouseover

I would like to know how to pass multiple arguments to the the function with onmouseover event handler in HTML.

Here is the following code in PHP ,

```
<a href='Page2.php?user=" . $userid . "' target='_blank' onMouseOver=\"writetxt('" . $info  "')\" onMouseOut=\"writetxt(0)\">"
```

I would like to pass 2 arguments to `writetxt()` function something like this :

```
writetxt($arg1, $arg2)

<a href='Page2.php?user=" . $userid . "' target='_blank' onMouseOver=\"writetxt('" . $info . "," . $img . "')\" onMouseOut=\"writetxt(0)\">"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like...

```
writetxt('" . $info . "', '" . $img . "');
                       ^  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
echo "<a href=\"Page2.php?user=" . $userid ."\" target=\"_blank\" onMouseOver=\"writetxt('" . $info . "','" . $img . "')\" onMouseOut=\"writetxt(0)\">" ;
```